# Software to track what files and folders an application accesses or creates?

Tags: c, winapi

Is there a software for windows that can use the winapi or something to detect folder access or file accesses by that application?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) does a great job of showing what a process is doing, including file and registry access.